# Allow user to chose amount of bundled products

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle

I am trying to achieve the following scenario and looking for a solution:

E-cigarette device is: £20.00 + 1 bottle of e-liquid or £25.00 + 4 bottles of e-liquid. The e-liquids are configurable (strength).

Can I use bundled product for that? Or I need to create 2 bundles?

Any suggestions how I can achieve the above?